# Removing permisions tag

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

[permisions](/questions/tagged/permisions) has 6 questions, no synonyms, no description and in every question it has been used in, it's when permission has been misspelled. (Except for one where permissions was spelled right in the question, but used the wrong tag). Is it possible to have this tag removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have manually retagged several of the questions, to [permissions](/questions/tagged/permissions). However, this appears like it's a tag that could recur in the future, and probably shouldn't be burninated, but made a synonym of [permissions](/questions/tagged/permissions). If a mod could possibly come in and take care of it, then we should be good to go!

Comment: It looks like just a typo that went unnoticed for a while. I don't think a synonym is really necessary.

Comment: Okay, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the moderator can safely remove this tag, so that in future no further post will use this tag again. I wonder, how was it approved in first place, since it is misspelled :)

Comment: If a user with sufficient rep (>= 1500, iirc) mistypes, it is created automatically.

Comment: The New Tag Deletionist Cabal usually takes care of these.  Usually.